# How much topsoil on top of clay to level sloping garden

Tags: lawn, grass, drainage, clay

Hi I have a separated garden first is lawn and the second was a play area with a (10m x 6m)membrane over clay with bark. We have now removed bark and want a level lawn but my problem is how do I level and what and how much do I use. We want to put a pool on but need it to be level.
So what combination would I use? Everyone has a different way..

- Hardcore/topsoil
- Shingle/ topsoil
- Hardcore/type1

I’m confused.... I’m gonna remove pool end of each summer n treat area but need your advice

Comment: do you want to change the membrane area into lawn or into an area for an above ground pool? You can't normally do both